# Quotation Template Builder - Solutions available

Tags: microsoft-word, templates

First of all, I went through all the different forums below and couldn't find the most appropriate one, so I chose this one which in my eyes looked a bit relevant. Hope this is not a problem!

We have to send out detailed proposals / quotations to our clients from time to time.  From time to time, we have built quite an large list of 'snippets' / 'templates' which we basically use to come up with a detailed proposal, without having to actually write everything each time.  Our system at the moment is one large MS Word file, where we remove the sections un-needed.  However, this is getting quite large and not really maintainable, and wanted to know if anyone knows any specific software / solutions which would help in this regards.

The proposal built is not just similar to an invoice with pricing, but more like a written proposal on the functionality of the system.  Our line of work is mainly web design / web development.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated, as I don't actually even know what to look for!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on web development you may wish to look into a commercial product to produce your final documents, most of which have the advantage of being fast and not requring Microsoft Word automation to run (which is great plus for a web application).

With such an application you can break down the parts of your templates in to different files and combine them using the application and merge them with data. This will help to keep track of documents and make things fast.

Check out [Aspose.com](http://www.aspose.com/) which seems good.

Comment: I think i was misunderstood - I was not referring to develop such a system, but need to use such a system for our company's needs.  Thus, there is no need for any form of software automation, or components like `Aspose`